# manually paint on QPainter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to paint on QPainter manually. I understand that if QWidget is the paintdevice, then QPainter has to operate inside the method paintEvent(). And also that paintEvent() gets called everytime the widget is updated.

What I am trying to do is take an array of coordinates from file and draw rectangles based on the coordinate array.

```
class timeline(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 700, 2000, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colors')
        #self.show()


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        print(event.type())
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        print("error2")
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        Y = 700
        for i in range(self.rows):
            randArr = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(3,1))
            qp.fillRect(QtCore.QRect(self.tldata[i,6], Y, self.tldata[i,7], 5), QtGui.QColor(randArr[0], randArr[1], randArr[2]))
```

self.tldata is the coordinate file that I will read in.

Currently, this is how the colored rectangle looks (in the dark blue). Essentially I want to be able have a multicolored rectangle. Each color within the larger rectangle will represent a specific time range

[image]

EDIT 1: when I run my full program, it continues to print("error2") as well as call self.drawRectangle(qp) when I move my window around. However, the event.type() returns 12 which is a **Paint** event. [Table of event types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html)

So I'm guessing that somehow resizing the mainwindow is causing a **Paint** event. What can potentially cause this behavior?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: For _Any help_,  I recommend you go through this Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-painting.html

Comment: What is your problem? I could provide an example of self.tldata to be able to understand you better.

Comment: @eyllanesc self.tldata is just an numpy array for my timestamps. I use the values I retrieve from self.tldata to draw rectangles on QPainter. But because of the requirement that paintEvent() is always called when something updates in the widget (ex. window resizing, switching apps, etc.), I am having trouble to draw the rectangles just once.

Comment: paintEvent is called continuously so you will have to paint it again, I do not understand what kind of answers you expect.

Comment: Why do not you want to draw the rectangles several times?

Comment: If you want to prevent drawing of individual rectangles at any call of `paintEvent()`, I see only one solution: Draw the rectangles into a `QPixmap` once, then draw this `QPixmap` in `paintEvent()`. For your luck, drawing into a `QPixmap` can be done with a `QPainter` as well. The `QPixmap`might be have the exact size of the widget. So, it might make sense to resize/rebuild it whenever a `resizeEvent()` is received.